# jQuery children() going deeper

Tags: jquery, children

```
<div class='main'>

<div>
        <div>
            <button></button>
        </div>
</div>
<ul>    
        <li>
            <img />
        </li>

        <li>
            <h1></h1>
        </li>

</ul>
<div>
        <span>
            <a href=""></a>
        </span>
</div>

</div>
```

Question: I want to select buttons, img, h1 and a. The only way to do this in jQuery (as I know) is $(.main).children().children().children(). 
But is there another way to select those elements in jQuery? (to not use so many times children())

Comment: `$(".main").find("button, img, h1, a")` will select all those elements at any level under `".main"` - but do you mean you want them from any level, or exactly three levels down?

Comment: `$("img, h1, a, button", ".main")`

Comment: @nnnnnn's is more simple. For image  - `$('li img').each(function(o){....})`. For `h1` - `$('li h1').each(function(o){....})`. For anchor - `$('span a').each(function(o){....})`.

Comment: Yuriy Rozhovetskiy share the best answear :) didn't know that $ can select elements like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="main">
   <div>
      <div>
         <button class="mustSelect"></button>
      </div>
   </div>
   <ul>
      <li>
         <img class="mustSelect" />
      </li>
      <li>
         <h1 class="mustSelect"></h1>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <div>
      <span>
      <a href="" class="mustSelect"></a>
      </span>
   </div>
```

Add the class(class="mustSelect") to the elements you need. Then in the js  you can refer those elements as below.

```
$('.mustSelect')
```

If ***you are unable to add a class***, use the following

```
$("button, img , h1 , a ", ".main")
```

It tells jquery to select the whatever the button, img , h1 , a in the .main class.

Hope this will help you out. If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you can use .find() method:

```
$('.main').find()
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery selectors work like CSS selectors:

```
var $button = $('.main > div > div > button');
```

You can also use `find()` method:

```
var $a = $('.main').find('a');
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 2):

Actually if you are trying to select all leaf nodes inside your "container div" you can try

```
$(".main :not(:has(*))")
```

This will select any elements at any level inside your "container div" which has no child elements.